# ARM NEON SIMD version 2

Tags: arm, simd, neon

What is the difference between NEON SIMD and NEON SIMD version 2 as in Cortex A15?

Answer (score 6):

It adds SIMD FMA instruction (VFMA.F32) and also mandates NEON half precision extension. NEONv2 is supported in ARM Cortex-A7, ARM Cortex-A15, and Qualcomm Krait (not sure about ARM Cortex-A5).

Comment: Krait has versions too but I don't even think recent ones support this.

Comment: I have [an app in Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.yeppp.cpuid) which detects supported instruction extensions. I tested it on Dragonboard (early dual-core Krait), and Nexus 4 (a more recent quad-core Krait), both support NEONv2. If you have a device with Krait CPU you may check it yourself.

Comment: I use that app now and then actually :) and you are right about later kraits having v2.

Comment: How do you read those features? I thought you need to be in supervisor mode to read configuration registers. Are you parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: I use several methods, including parsing of /proc/cpuinfo. I suggest that you look into the source code if you want the details.

Comment: There was some recent changes for krait & cpuinfo. https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2222161/ So some Kraits has the idiv but didn't show up in cpuinfo previously.

Comment: Yeppp! library will detect DIV instructions regardless of whether they are manifested by Linux kernel

Answer (score 4):

It is not that much of a difference, from [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406b/index.html):

(in reverse order of definitions)

> > Advanced SIMDv2 is an OPTIONAL extension to the ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R profiles.
> >     Advanced SIMDv2 adds both the Half-precision Extension and the fused 
> >     multiply-add instructions to the features of Advanced SIMDv1.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > Advanced SIMDv1 can be extended by the OPTIONAL Half-precision Extension, 
> >     that provides conversion functions in both directions between half-precision 
> >     floating-point and single-precision floating-point.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > The Advanced SIMD architecture extension, its associated implementations, and supporting software, are 
> >     commonly referred to as NEON™
> >      technology.