# ARMv6 floating point operations per cycle

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, hpc, armv6

How many floating point operations(add, mul) per cycle an ARMv6(ARM1176JZFS - Raspberry Pi model B) processor can execute? This is for get the teorical peak performance of HPC(High Performance Computing) cluster:

Node performance in GFlops = (CPU speed in GHz) x (number of CPU cores) x (CPU instruction per cycle) x (number of CPUs per node)

Comment: http://www.arm.com/products/processors/classic/arm11/arm1176.php

Comment: didnt someone just ask this?  is this a duplicate?

Comment: @dwelch, yes, I asked that a few days ago [peak-flops-per-cycle-for-arm11-and-cortex-a7-cores-in-raspberry-pi-1-and-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976071/peak-flops-per-cycle-for-arm11-and-cortex-a7-cores-in-raspberry-pi-1-and-2). I guess other people are interested in this as well.

Comment: I can't imagine any HPC cluster using ARMv6. It may be a cluster using many (thousands) of ARMVv6/raspberry Pi 1 but it won't be HPC.

Comment: Of course Z boson, "don't imagine it". It won't be a production cluster, it's only for educational or prototype purpose. Coming soon the ARM processors will come to dominate the computers and supercomputers ;) . Salut

Comment: @Zboson: ARMv6 no, but ARMv8+GPU - [yep!](http://www.montblanc-project.eu/press-corner/news/innovative-embedded-architecture-hpc-made-europe) :)